# Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value for UIButton setting title

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, viewcontroller

```
import UIKit

class PopOverViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var textForPopUp: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var imge1: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var imge2: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var imge3: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var imge4: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var imge5: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var yesButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var noButton: UIButton!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:Selector("imageTapped:"))
    tapGestureRecognizer.delegate = self
    print("Inside POP over View Controller viewDidLoad")    
    imge1.image = UIImage(named: "like")
    imge1.tag = 0
    imge1.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    imge1.userInteractionEnabled = true
    imge2.image = UIImage(named: "like")
    imge2.tag = 1
    imge2.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    imge2.userInteractionEnabled = true
    imge3.image = UIImage(named: "like")
    imge3.tag = 2
    imge3.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    imge3.userInteractionEnabled = true
    imge4.image = UIImage(named: "like")
    imge4.tag = 3
    imge4.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    imge4.userInteractionEnabled = true
    imge5.image = UIImage(named: "like")
    imge5.tag = 4
    imge5.userInteractionEnabled = true
    imge5.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
func imageTapped(sender : UIImageView){
    if(sender.tag < 3){
        print("Why didn't you like our app?")
    }
    else {
        print("We will be redirecting you shortly")
    }

}

func initializeData(buttonTitle1 button1: String? = nil , buttonTitle button2 : String? = nil , titleText title : String? = nil){

    if(button1 != nil) {

        yesButton.setTitle(button1, forState: .Normal)
    }
    if(button2 != nil){
        noButton.setTitle(button2, forState: .Normal)
    }
        if(title != nil){
        textForPopUp.text = title
    }


}
}
```

Error is at line `yesButton.setTitle(button1, forState: .Normal)`
Unexpectedly found nil is the error .
I call

> initializeData()

from another controller. 
I saw in the XCode console that all my ImageView and Button objects were nil. I think that is causing the error. How do I solve it?

EDIT: 
called initializeData() here

```
func popView(sender : MyOrdersViewController){
    let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name : "Main" , bundle: nil)
    var popViewController : PopOverViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("popUp") as! PopOverViewController
    popViewController.initializeData(buttonTitle1: "Yes", buttonTitle: "No", titleText: "How do you you find our app?")
    let popOverMenuViewController = popViewController.popoverPresentationController
    popOverMenuViewController?.permittedArrowDirections = .Any
    popOverMenuViewController?.delegate = self
    popOverMenuViewController?.sourceView = sender.view
    presentViewController(popViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: Can you post the line where you called initializeData()?

Comment: @BenjaminLowry see the edit.

Comment: probably your vc has not yet been initialized, in fact, for how did the call should be the button to nil

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is, you've created an instance of `PopOverViewController` and before the view has loaded (when all your outlets are still `nil`) you're calling `initializeData(_:)` which is accessing your outlets.

You'll either have to do something which makes the view load first or you could pass the button titles first and load it in `viewWillAppear` / `viewDidLoad` of `PopOverViewController`.

And be sure to check the connections of your outlets. Very often people forget to connect or adjust the connection after changing it.

A small example to pass the titles:

```
func popView(sender: MyOrdersViewController){
    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name : "Main" , bundle: nil)
    var controller = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("popUp") as! PopOverViewController
    controller.titles = ["title1": "yes", "title2": "no"]
    presentViewController(popViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And how to set the titles:

```
class PopOverViewController: UIViewController {

    var titles: [String: String] = [:]

    override viewWillAppear() {
        super.viewWillAppear()

        yesButton.setTitle(titles["title1"] ?? "No title", forState: .Normal)
         noButton.setTitle(titles["title2"] ?? "No title", forState: .Normal)
    }
}
```

Using `titles["title1"] ?? "No title"` will set the title of your button to `"No title"` if `titles["title1"]` is `nil`. This is a safe approach by not implicitly unwrapping an optional. It's equivalent to:

```
titles["title1"] != nil ? titles["title1"]! : "No title" }
```

Comment: How can I initialize my buttons and image objects? I'm not being able to. @Eendje

Comment: Well, like my answer suggested. You pass the information you want to set, e.g. the titles of your buttons. And then in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidLoad` you can set those titles to your buttons. I'd recommend to use either a dictionary or array to pass the titles if you want to pass a lot of titles.

Answer (score 0):

Once make sure, whether the outlet for the button is attached(linked) properly from the storyboard or xib viewcontroller or not.

Make the PopOverController as super class for other controller from where you calling this method.

Note: root controller of project should be UINavigationController.